# Rails console doesn't work as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very new to Ruby and Rails. when i want to create some application_name in rails by typing the commands (rails new sample_app) it is creating a new folder.  while typing suppose rails console command, it is producing console folder in my  directory rather switching to the rails console. i m feeling so irritating please help me where am i doing mistakes and i  have installed rails 2.3.14 and i am using ruby on rails 3.2

eagerly waiting for your positive answer.. thank u

```
bikram@Bikram:~/rails_projects$ rails console
      create  
      create  app/controllers
      create  app/helpers
      create  app/models
      create  app/views/layouts
      create  config/environments
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/locales
      create  db
      create  doc
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  log
      create  public/images
      create  public/javascripts
      create  public/stylesheets
      create  script/performance
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/functional
      create  test/integration
      create  test/performance
      create  test/unit
      create  vendor
      create  vendor/plugins
      create  tmp/sessions
      create  tmp/sockets
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/pids
      create  Rakefile
      create  README
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookie_verification_secret.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  script/about
      create  script/console
      create  script/dbconsole
      create  script/destroy
      create  script/generate
      create  script/runner
      create  script/server
      create  script/plugin
      create  script/performance/benchmarker
      create  script/performance/profiler
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/index.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  public/images/rails.png
      create  public/javascripts/prototype.js
      create  public/javascripts/effects.js
      create  public/javascripts/dragdrop.js
      create  public/javascripts/controls.js
      create  public/javascripts/application.js
      create  doc/README_FOR_APP
      create  log/server.log
      create  log/production.log
      create  log/development.log
      create  log/test.log
      create  vendor/rails
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete your sample_app project and reinstall Rails - I can see
   that your rails binary is 2.3.x version.
2. Create new project
3. cd to created project
4. then try to start rails console.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you start from the basics, this is a good resource: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/